# Notification runtime permission which is blocks my App working flow -Android13

Tags: android, sdk, android-notifications, runtime-permissions, android-13

Our app working flow is blocked when I run on Android 13, In android 12 and lower working as expected but In Android-13 "Notification permission dialog is appearing" and If i ignore that dialog, next time I can't launch my application.

I need suggestions here.

Update 1:

I just tried with by change the value of compileSdkVersion  and targetSdkVersion into 33.

Notification permission dialog is  NOT appeared, Behaviour of our app is as expected but if the sdkversion 32 and below I'm getting this error.

Comment: You need to request notification permission for Android 33 and higher. You can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75812264/8033785

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your versions to API 33 to use runtime permission requests. Because it's special permission for only Android13+