# Android app foreground mode only showing notification after runtime permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, foregroundnotification

Not sure whether this is intended behaviour or I am doing something wrong. I upgraded an older app to target SDK 34. The app has a foregroundservice. According to the docs I need to show a notification to the user while being in foreground mode.

I added the permission "POST_NOTIFICATIONS". (Also: FOREGROUND_SERVICE and FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK. And foregroundServiceType is mediaPlayback) Now when I install the app, the notification does not show when it goes in foreground mode. Only when I go into my devices' settings->Notifications->App notifications and switch the notifications on for my app, the notification shows as intended. Alternatively, I am able to ask runtime permission to show the notification, and the notification indeed shows once the user allows it.

My question: is it normal behaviour that the notification is not shown (whereas it is a prerequisite for forground mode)? Should I ask permission when the user opens the app for the first time? Or should I use some other permission to avoid haveing the user to do some action before the notification required by Android is shown?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/75812264/8475893

Answer (score 0):

According to your question and statement you stated notification shows when user
allow the permission then you should ask for permission or not?

then would say it is necessary to ask for notification permission from android 13 without that you can't show notification to user ,you can ask for runtime permission as used to do for camera ,external storage etc.

Comment: To show notifications, your app must declare post_notifications in the manifest AND ask for permission to show notifications at runtime. There are a few cases in which you may not ask the permission, but this is not the case. https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission

Comment: Can you explain this mysterious conundrum: « Apps don't need to request the POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission in order to launch a foreground service. However, apps must include a notification when they start a foreground service«?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).